# strange behavior of matplotlib plot on numpy matrix element

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using *python3.X*.

I came across some very strange behavior in matplotlib on a numpy matrix element
as an ilustration I wanted to plot a simple **sinc()** function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t=np.matrix(np.linspace(-10,10,1024))
x=np.sinc(t)

plt.plot(t,x,color='blue', linestyle='solid', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

*The above piece of code generates:*
[image: empty figure - STRANGE]

While replacing the *plt.plot(...)* with:

```
plt.plot(t,x,'-ob')
```

*generates:*

[image: desired result with 'o']

I could not figure out the reason for this behavior, would appreciate some help

Comment: In your 1st case `plt.plot` is interpreting your input as 1024 data sets and plotting each of them individually. Replace with `t.T` and `x.T` ( transpose your arrays) and it works fine

Comment: The same is true for your 2nd case, but since you are using dots rather than lines the output looks Ok.

Comment: @Brenlla can you post it as answer, for me to accept, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), when using 2-D arrays, `plot` interprets the columns as separate data sets. Therefore, in your 1st case you are plotting 1024 lines with one point each. Since line plots work by drawing lines *between* points, nothing is being displayed:

```
t=np.matrix(np.linspace(-10,10,1024))
x=np.sinc(t)

plt.plot(t,x,color='blue', linestyle='solid', linewidth=2)
# plot shows nothing
```

Transpose your arrays to single column and it works fine:

```
plt.plot(t.T,x.T,color='blue', linestyle='solid', linewidth=2)
# plot shows line
```

The 2nd case works fine because when plotting dots, one is drawn for each data point. It is probably still faster to just plot one data set though:

```
plt.plot(t.T,x.T,'-ob')
# same output, probably faster
```

Comment: Another question, why when i change `t` to  `np.array` it works without the transpose; what is the essential difference between the 2 types?; Also would appreciate an upvote

Comment: It is recommended you use `array` rather than [`matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html). Matrices are always 2-D, whereas arrays can have any dimensionality. For this case, if your create 1-D arrays (check `t.ndim`), transposing does nothing since there is only one dimension.

Comment: I check the `ndim` and as you said, indeed for the `np.array` its just *1D* while for the `np.matrix` is *2D*; Thanks for pointing the problem